# XSLT transformation for xml with multiple order tag creating corresponding a XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt

This is my xml file for which I am to write an xsl file. Purpose for this xsl is to use for xml to perform some  operation.

## Input Xml

```
    <ns1:SalesOrder xmlns:ns1="http://tanole/SO11/ERP_PD_EMS/RD_SalesOrder_Defirm">
  <Rder>
     <Order>
            <OrderNo>457</OrderNo>
            <LineNo>1</LineNo>
            <SerialNO>23</SerialNO>
            <VNo>567</VNo>
        </Order>
        <Order>
           <OrderNo>457</OrderNo>
            <LineNo>2</LineNo>
            <SerialNO>29</SerialNO>
            <VNo>567</VNo>
        </Order>
        <Order>
           <OrderNo>458</OrderNo>
            <LineNo>1</LineNo>
            <SerialNO>96</SerialNO>
            <VNo>543</VNo>
        </Order>
        <Order>
           <OrderNo>458</OrderNo>
            <LineNo>2</LineNo>
            <SerialNO>32</SerialNO>
            <VNo>543</VNo>
        </Order>
    </Rder>
</ns1:SalesOrder>

    Expecting Output 
    <Order VNo="567" OrderNo="457"> 
    <OrderLines>
    <OrderLine  LineNo="1" SerialNO="23"/>
    <OrderLine  LineNo="2" SerialNO="29"/>
    <OrderLines>
    </Order>

    <Order VNo="543" OrderNo="458"> 
    <OrderLines>
    <OrderLine  LineNo="1" SerialNO="96"/>
    <OrderLine  LineNo="2" SerialNO="32"/>
    <OrderLines>
    </Order>
```

I am trying to implement this logic in my xsl file, but unable to get so.This is what I am currently trying to do, I have tried a few things and cannot figure out a way to do what I need.

```
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:output method="xml"  version="1.0" indent="yes"/> 
          <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
         <Order>
              <xsl:attribute name="VNo"><xsl:value-of select="VNo"/></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="OrderNo"><xsl:value-of select="DocumentType"/></xsl:attribute>
        <OrderLines>
            <xsl:element name="OrderLine">
              <xsl:if test ="not(preceding::Order[LineNo/text() = current()/LineNo/text()] )">
                     <xsl:attribute name="SerialNO"><xsl:value-of select="OrderNo"/></xsl:attribute>
                     <xsl:attribute name="LineNo"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:attribute>

                  </xsl:if>
                </xsl:element>
                   <!--  </xsl:if>
                     </xsl:if>-->
                </OrderLines>
        </Order>
        </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a "grouping" problem, and as you are using XSLT 1.0, the technique to use is called "Muenchian Grouping". Have a good read of http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html which explains all about it. Thank!

Comment: is their  any alternate way for doing this  ?Tim C

Comment: Muenchian Grouping may look overwhelming, but once you get your head around it, it really is the preferred way of doing grouping in XSLT 1.0. If you can use XSLT 2.0 though, you can use `xsl:for-each-group`. Check out http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html

Comment: Time C Could  you provide me a sample for  doing grouping in XSLT 1.0. according to above input. i Couldn't see any examples  for that.

Comment: I can! But first can you correct your input XML sample, as it is not currently valid. You have a namespace prefix which is not declared (`ns1:SalesOrder`), and also you have opening `VNo` tags, but closing `Vno` tags. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sorry for  that Tim c I have  updated now. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Muenchian grouping, your first define key to represent your group

```
<xsl:key name="orders" match="Order" use="OrderNo" />
```

This assumes the same `VNo` occurs for each distinct `OrderNo`. Then, to get the first occurrence of the `Order` elements for each distinct `OrderNo`, you do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="Rder/Order[generate-id() = generate-id(key('orders', OrderNo)[1])]">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="orders" match="Order" use="OrderNo" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <SalesOrders>
        <xsl:for-each select="Rder/Order[generate-id() = generate-id(key('orders', OrderNo)[1])]">
          <Order VNo="{VNo}" OrderNo="{OrderNo}"> 
            <OrderLines>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="key('orders', OrderNo)" />
            </OrderLines>
          </Order>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </SalesOrders>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Order">
        <OrderLine  LineNo="{LineNo}" SerialNO="{SerialNO}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you could have multiple `VNo` elements for the same `OrderNo` you would need to define you key like so

```
<xsl:key name="orders" match="Order" use="concat(OrderNo, '|', VNo)" />
```

You would also need to change any uses of the key accordingly.

Comment: Hi Tim C it is not  giving any output xml details.

Comment: The XSLT does work on the input in your question. Does your actual XML have namespace prefixes (`ns1:`) on all the elements, not just the root `SalesOrder` one?

Comment: Yeah It's  some tag mistake  its working fine Thanks  lots Tim C.  :-)

Comment: could  you tell how we can replace value for LineNo suppose  we are getting -0010 to we need 1 and like  0020 to 2.